# How to use mysql spatial with prepared statements

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, spatial, wkt

I've got two scenarios, using the following statement:

```
 INSERT INTO areas (name, polygon) VALUES (?, POLYGON(?,?,?,?,?,?))
```

Will result in errors like this:

```
Illegal non geometric ''58.03665463092348 14.974815566795314'' value found during parsing
```

What seems to be the problem here is that my lat and longitudes are quoted as texts within the POLYGON().

However,according to the WKT format I need another set of () in my statement:

```
  INSERT INTO areas (name, polygon) VALUES (?, POLYGON((?,?,?,?,?,?)))
```

which will only result in the following error:

```
 Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

I'm at a loss here, how do I use prepared statements along with mysql spatial information?

Comment: Turns out if I simply toss everything into a query without first preparing a statement (not even escaping the values) it works like a charm...

but I really want to escape the input since it is user generated, any hints as of why I cannot escape the lat/longitude data?

Comment: It would help to see the table's schema.

Comment: It's a simple polygon column along with a spatial index:

CREATE TABLE `areas` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `polygon` polygon NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  SPATIAL KEY `spatial` (`polygon`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin$$